# Can all functions be restricted to a dense set from which they may be continuously extended?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ ($f$ is not necessarily continuous), will there always be a dense set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that, if we restrict $f$ to $S$, we may then extend it to a continuous function of $\mathbb{R}$? (If the answer is "no," I would like some sort of counterexample.)

I have been trying to approach this with the $\mathbb{R}$-specific definitions of continuity and dense sets, but it has occurred to me that this might be a bad angle. I did manage to prove (or at least outline a proof) that, for any interval $I$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and for any $\epsilon>0$, there exist $x,y\in I$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. I was able to further deduce that there must exist an interval $J$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with length $\epsilon$ such that $|\{x\in I:f(x)\in J\}|=\mathfrak{c}$. However, I am not sure where to go from here, or if these results are even useful to answering the question.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample: let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1;&x\geq0,\\0;&x<0.\end{cases}$$ If you restrict this to a dense subset of $\mathbb R$ and then extend it back in any way, the left and right limits at $0$ still won't agree, so the extension won't be continuous.

Here's a somewhat weaker statement that you might like: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72800/every-real-function-has-a-dense-set-on-which-its-restriction-is-continuous.